# Using a list and a normal value

Tags: python, sql, arrays, sqlite

So, I'm trying to do a SQLite prepared statement, something like this:

definition

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab (
    _id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    obj text NOT NULL,
    val int NOT NULL
    ) ;''')
```

I want to execute the following prepared statement:

```
list_of_vars=['foo','bar']
statement = "SELECT * FROM tab WHERE obj IN ({0}) AND val BETWEEN ? AND ?".format(', '.join(['?' * len(list_of_vars)]))
```

My solution to this is quite ugly at the moment, and I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing this...

```
vals=list_of_vars
vals.append(0)
vals.append(100)
c.execute(statement, vals)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate lists quite easily:

```
c.execute(statement, list_of_vars + [0, 100])
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easier way... Python always has an elegant solution for simple problems, even if it isn't always obvious... Thanks!